# Jquery to select 2 fields from the object array and save them in object array

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an array with objects and I am trying to get all the batchnumbers and and batch details in to an array of objects

```
    var data = [{
        Date: "09/28/2016"
        Batch: 10
        FirstName: "Betty"
        LastName : "White"
       ***: "***".... },
     { Date: "09/28/2016"
       Batch: 10
       FirstName: "Betty"
       LastName : "White"
       ***: "***"....},......]
```

Jquery code to get into an array

```
        var result = Data.map(function(a) { return [a.Date,a.Batch]};
```

What is the way to get them as array of objects?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

map already returns an array, so rather than returning an array of arrays, simply return an object from within the map function like so:

```
var result = data.map(function(elem, index) {
    return {
        date: a.Date,
        batch: a.Batch
    };
});
```

Comment: Is there any alternative for map to get object array, As I dont want to create new variables

Comment: @userabc I'm confused =\ This code will give you an array of objects (as you've asked for) with properties that you can access. For example, you can say result[0].date and it will return "09/28/2016". What data structure are you looking for it to return?

Answer (score 0):

You can return it as objects as follows

```
var result = data.map(function(a) { 
     return {
       "date" : d.date, 
       "batch" : d.batch
     }
  });
```